# Disable Autosave in Microsoft Access

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I am a newbie with access and want to know something.

I created a form and it doesn't work the way I want it to. When I enter data to the form fields the data is saved automatically. I want to disable this auto save feature and make the user click the save button to save the record because I want to run a code when a new recode is added or an existing record is changed.

A quick solution would be really appreciated.

Comment: Use an unbound form. You will miss out on a lot of the benefits of MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

Use an unbound Form and create a vba code to save your data into the table on the on_lick event of the custom save button

Answer (score 0):

Use Form_BeforeUpdate event of the form to cancel autosave, as shown below:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If MsgBox("Do you want to save the changes?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
    Me.Undo
    Cancel = True
    End If
  End Sub
```